# Google, OAuth, and iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have been beating my head all day trying to figure this out. 
Don't understand why Google can't have the same process as Twitter, Instagram, Tumblr, LinkedIn, etc (i have all these working).

I am wanting to have a button that will open Safari (I want to follow the same process as the other Social Media Sites), ask the user to log into Google, and then callback to my app with the Access Token.

I have all the things set up in Google Dev, I can log into my Google account, but the callback won't go back to my app.

With the others, I had a URL scheme in XCode with the format ig[clientID]://authorize and was able to pass this in the url to the endpoint.

For "Client ID for iOS application" or "Client ID for native application" my callbacks are are (and they won't let you change it)

```
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
http://localhost
```

For "Client ID for web application" your callback has to the in the form of

```
http://
https://
```

I have looked online and have had no luck.

Does anyone know how to setup Xcode project to handle these callbacks that google gives you?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the ready made [Google+ iOS SDK](http://goo.gl/9cTqyZ) instead of going through all this process of integrating the Google+ authentication in your iOS application. It is much easier to authenticate Google users with the underlying implementation hidden from the developer using this SDK and writing just a few lines of code. You can find all the details of that on this [page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in).

Comment: Ya....but I really wanted to follow the same "flow" as the others for maintenance and common look and feel. That was my reasoning.

Comment: From what I understand from your description above, I am sure you'll be able to keep the "flow" almost the same but there are always differences in implementation when working with different products/technologies. Although I understand your point of view as well